# No funciona borra una fila en sqlite en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estoy implementado un squlite en Android Studio y lo he creado asi:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int BD_version = 1;
public static  final String TABLE_NOMBRE = "SQLiteGPS";
public static final  String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final  String COLUMN_DIRECCION = "direccion";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TABLE_NOMBRE, null, BD_version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOMBRE
            + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_DIRECCION +  " VARCHAR); ";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SQLiteGPS";
  db.execSQL(sql);
  onCreate(db);
}

public  boolean addData (String insertar){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_DIRECCION,insertar);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NOMBRE,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1){
        return  false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor getListaContenidos(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NOMBRE,null);
    return data;
}

public void deleteItemDB(String itemID){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NOMBRE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_DIRECCION + "='" + itemID + "'");
    db.close();
  }
 }
```

Yo necesito borrar solo la primera columna de la tabla, para eso estoy usando esto en el MainActivity:

```
DatabaseHelper miBD = new DatabaseHelper(this);

bBorrarItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    miBD.deleteItemDB("1"); 
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Borrado el 1er item de la Tabla",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```

No tengo errores en la compilacion pero no logro borrar la primera fila de la tabla, cual es mi error?

Answer (score 0):

intentas enviar el id del registro el cual deseas eliminar, pero tu mètodo trata de buscar en otro campo que es "direccion" (COLUMN_DIRECCION), define que sea en el campo "id" pero este valor debe ser entero:

```
public void deleteItemDB(int itemID){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NOMBRE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_DIRECCION + "='" + itemID + "'");
     db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NOMBRE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=" + itemID);
    db.close();
  }
 }
```

Por lo tanto esta serìa la forma de llamar el registro:

```
miBD.deleteItemDB(1);
```